# Query returning true/false

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I recently started learning `Prolog` and have come across an issue.

The following has been loaded into `Prolog`:

```
likes(john, apple).
likes(john, pear).
likes(john, grapes).
likes(bill, mango).
likes(bill, apple).
```

I am writing a predicate `all_like(What, List)` that should return `True` if all the people in `List` like the fruit in `What`.

Eg:

```
all_like(apple,[john, bill]).
```

should return:

```
true ;
false.
```

`all_like(grapes,[john, bill]).`

should return:

```
false.
```

I have the following code:

```
all_like(What,List) :- check_list(What,List).

check_list(What,[]) :- write('true').
check_list(What, [X|Rest]) :- likes(X,What), check_list(What,Rest).
check_list(What, [X|Rest]) :- \+ likes(X,What), write('false').
```

My results are:

**1st Query**

```
true
true .
```

**2nd Query**

```
false
true .
```

Would anyone know why I'm getting these results?

What is the significance of the second boolean value being outputted?

Finally, is the `.` appearing after a space of significance?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prolog already indicates whether a predicate succeeds (`true` or `yes`) or fails (`false` or `no`), so you're doing too much work in your predicate when you (a) explicitly write out "true" on success, and (b) you try to succeed on a failure case and write out failure. It's best to let the failing case just fail, then Prolog will show the failure.

As an aside, your `check_list` predicate is superfluous and you can just use `all_likes`. So this is really all you need:

```
all_likes(_, []).             % An empty list likes anything
all_likes(What, [X|Rest]) :-  % All of [X|Rest] likes What if... 
    likes(X, What),           % X likes What and...
    all_likes(What, Rest).    % All of Rest likes What
```

In SWI Prolog, you'll see these results:

```
?- all_likes(apple,[john, bill]).
true ;
false.

?- all_likes(grapes,[john, bill]).
false.
```

In GNU Prolog, the output looks like this:

```
| ?- all_likes(apple,[john, bill]).

true ? ;

no
| ?- all_likes(grapes,[john, bill]).

no
| ?-
```

Comment: Thanks lurker, that makes a lot more sense. May I ask why `false` is displayed after `true ;` in the first example?

Comment: @Giri "false" is display after "true" because Prolog had a choice point to go back to and check for more solutions, but didn't find additional answers. So SWI Prolog outputs "false". You can see in the GNU Prolog case, you get "no" rather than "false", and it means the same thing: no more solutions.